# How to change the cursor on an image on mouse move

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular6

In an Angular 7 application, I'm trying to implement left and right arrows for an image slideshow. If the mouse is hovered on the left half of the image, it should show a left arrow, and a right arrow on the right half. Clicking the image then will take the user to either the next or previous image in the array of images. Something like this: https://wells-demo.squarespace.com/human-nature-wells/uml9t64gkm48jijkt8y6slmtd0jush

```
<img src="url" (click)="navigate()">
```

I tried to set up something with @HostListener, but can't quite figure out how to progress.

```
urls = [url1, url2, url3, ....url10];
currIndex = 2;
url = urls[currIndex];

    @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
        onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
            //console.log(event.pageX);
            //console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft);
            //not completely sure what to do here...

        }

navigate() {
  if (leftHalf) { //how to figure this out?
     prevImage();
  } else {
     nextImage();
  }

nextImage() {
   this.url = this.urls[this.currIndex + 1];
}

prevImage() {
  this.url = this.urls[this.currIndex - 1]
}
```

1) How do I change the mouse cursor to a left arrow based on the position?
2) How to detect if left half or right half was clicked on?

Appreciate any help I can get on this!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of offsetWidth of the element and offsetX of the mousemove event.

```
if(event.offsetX > element.offsetWidth / 2) {
  // right half
} else {
  // left half
}
```

To change the pointer's you have to make use of add/remove class using the cursor property. Refer this https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/

Answer (score 0):

check out the below code for adding arrows as per your requirement

```css
.left_div{
cursor:w-resize;
float:left
}

.right_div{
cursor:n-resize;
float:right
}
```

```html
<div class="left_div">this is left div</div>
<div class="right_div">this is right div</div>
```